# Entity Framework db.SaveChanges not working when run within a Task()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have the following in my WebAPI controller:

```
  Task.Run(() => _userService.LoginWork(model.Username));
```

Where LoginWork has:

```
  // var user = db.Users where... 
  user.LoggedIn = DateTime.UtcNow;
  db.SaveChanges()
```

A really simple operation that I'm trying to execute without blocking the WebAPI work.  When I don't run this within a Task, it works fine.  But when I run within the Task, the db is never updated.  What's going on here?

Comment: can you please update your question with Loginwork method ?

Comment: @FrebinFrancis done, it's a simple get and update

Comment: No i want to see the method declaration and also the full definition.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/data/jj819165.aspx this post might help i think you need to use `await db.SaveChangesAsync();`

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to try to guess here the issue without seeing the entire code.

You're issuing a new task, outside of the WebApi request context, and you have a EntityFramework context (or repository dependent on the context) injected by IoC container, and that EntityFramework context is configured as instance per request.

That will cause that method to throw an ObjectDisposedException, but because is inside an async Task, you don't actually see the exception.